# Changing order of fields or properties in watch window

Tags: c#, debugging, watch

Visual studio 2012 (at least that one) seems to be sorting all fields / properties in struct / class in alphabetical order. Is there some mechanism to disable this sorting or overriding.
I would prefer to bring most important stuff up, and with lowest priority down.

Better if this would not require super heavy coding, or somehow hidden complexity.

(Not to fight with each class separately, may be solve it on generics / reflection level)

Answer (score 0):

OzCode's Reveal feature does exactly this - it let's you "star" the fields or properties you deem important, and reorders the display so they'll always appear on top. OzCode will always remember these preferences, even when you're debugging in a different solution.

See videos:

[Intro](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mvAsZe8xetM)

[Instructional Video](http://vimeo.com/m/97641391)

Full disclaimer: I am a co-creator of OzCode

Comment: Rather difficult to use - what I have tried by myself. (Quick test)

Main problem is that window is somehow floating over cursor, I would like to attach it permanently in visual studio like watch window. Typical debug scenario is to look at "this" - difficult to watch that variable ?

Comment: @TarmoPikaro You can hit the "Pin" button to pin the variable display to the code editor.

Comment: Only in floating form, not the same as watch window.

Comment: After I've understood that ozcode plugin overrides default visual studio behavior for quick watch, and moreover it does not have "pin" button to pin watched variable, I've successfully removed OzCode plugin.